# How do I look for nonzero values

Tags: python, flags

How do I look for a non-zero value in “things” within python and create flags.

- If there not is a non-zero value then I have to create a timeout flag.
- If there is a Non-zero then I need to clear the timeout flag
- return things

  ```
  def look_things(self, size)

       things = self.read(size)

       return things
  ```

Comment: Do you mean a non-zero length of `things`? If not, you need to describe the problem better. Show example values of `things`, and what you want to match.

Comment: Looking for non-zero value within the variable.

Comment: That's the same thing you wrote in the question. If it wasn't clear the first time, saying it again won't help.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a non-zero “length” of things.

Comment: Then just check `if len(things) > 0:` what's the problem?

Comment: How would I check if I’m looking for nonzero in an array?

Comment: `if any(x != 0 for x in things)`

Comment: That was in my original answer, but I changed it because you said you were looking for the length, not a value in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `len()` function to test the length of `things`.

```
if len(things) > 0:
    self.clear_timeout_flag()
else:
    self.set_timeout_flag()
```